# Spinning Cube Texture

Tags: three.js

Im trying to add a texture to my spinning cube but I have no idea where is the problem! Cube shows up but the texture is not. Tried to change the colour also, but it wouldn't change. Im so new in this. So please advise.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 30, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
// mouse controls
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
controls.autoRotate = true;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

// add cube
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x0fff10} );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

// load a texture, set wrap mode to repeat
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "http://packageonly.tk/1.jpg" );
texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.repeat.set( 4, 4 );

camera.position.z = 10;

var render = function () {
  requestAnimationFrame( render );

  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>EX3</title>
 <script src="http://packageOnly.tk/three.min.js"></script> 
 <script src="http://packageOnly.tk/OrbitControls.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 
 <script src="js/js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might find [this article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-textures.html) useful

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the texture on the [material.map](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshBasicMaterial.map) property:

```
// ...

// load a texture, set wrap mode to repeat
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "http://packageonly.tk/1.jpg" );
texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.repeat.set( 4, 4 );

// NOTE: Set the texture map to use on the material
material.map = texture;

camera.position.z = 10;

// ...
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to fix cross-origin issue for the texture. But approximately it should be like this (also note you did not have any lights):

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 30, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
// mouse controls
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
controls.autoRotate = true;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


// load a texture, set wrap mode to repeat
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.crossOrigin = '';
var texture = loader.load( "http://packageonly.tk/1.jpg" );
texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.repeat.set( 4, 4 );

// add cube
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {map:texture, specular: 0xFFFFFF,
    shininess: 30,} );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

let light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xeeffee, 0.8);
    light1.position.set(-5, 2, 2);
    scene.add(light1);
    
let light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffeeff, 0.8);
    light2.position.set(5, 2, -2);
    scene.add(light2);    


camera.position.z = 10;

var render = function () {
  requestAnimationFrame( render );

  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>EX3</title>
 <script src="http://packageOnly.tk/three.min.js"></script> 
 <script src="http://packageOnly.tk/OrbitControls.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 
 <!-- script src="js/js.js"></script -->
</body>
</html>
```